# What new tricks can an old dog learn?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, ado.net, webforms

Back in 2006 I've created a web site using asp.net 2.0. At that time, I had used Web Forms and classic ADO.NET SQL queries to connect to the underlying database. I've also used a fair amount of XSLT.

Today, the site still stands (it has gone through various upgrades but it is still based on Web Forms and simple SQL queries) but I believe it really needs to be upgraded as far as its technological infrastructure is concerned.

What is the next step I should take to move forward? A bit of ajax? JQuery maybe? Rewrite it in asp.net mvc? Replace SQL with typed datasets or even ling to sql? And what is the best way to embrace APIs such as twitter's?

So, can an old dog learn new tricks?

Comment: This question is much too subjective for SO.

Comment: @nonnb This would not be on-topic on [programmers.SE] either.  Look at there [faq](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So why do you believe the site's infrastructure needs to be upgraded?  If the site is running and performing well after 6 years of load and data, then what factors are causing you to think you need to upgrade it?

- Are there features that you want to implement (or users are asking for) that you can't implement with the current infrastructure?
- Is maintenance difficult and brittle, and every time you upgrade, you spend weeks fixing bugs introduced?
- Are there integrations that you'd like users to be able to do so that they can extend your application's functionality and/or data to their own applications?

Those reasons above could be reasons to upgrade, but I can't really tell you.

But as far as some of your questions about what to upgrade:

- **a bit of AJAX?**  It depends on what your current infrastructure looks like, but it's not too hard to introduce and you can isolate it
  pretty well with a service layer.
- **jQuery?**  Again, it depends on
  how your pages are structured.  If you have a lot of master page
  re-written IDs and very few classes on your DOM elements, using
  jQuery right off the bat may be tough as you'll have to figure out
  how to get your selectors in line.
- **Replace SQL with Typed
  DataSets?**  Please don't do that.  Honestly, if you go with
  Linq-to-SQL or EF, you'll probably take a slight performance hit
  compared to using ADO.NET with DataReaders (if that's what you're
  using).
- **Can an old dog learn new tricks?**  Always.  The learning
  never stops.

I would just advise not to upgrade just to upgrade.  Make sure you have legitimate business reasons for doing so.

Hope this helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Exactly. I've both maintenance and extensibility issues. The sql queries are killing me and so is the web forms model, I guess. For example, passing querystring parameters make the site less SEO-friendly. What I need is to embrace a new technology that can handle all the bells and whistles of the modern web. In other words, what is the next logical step after asp.net 2.0 that will not require a total mind shift or brain surgery to learn?

Comment: I've kind of gone through something similar over the past year or two.  (And it did take that long.)  I took a ASP.NET 2.0 app and moved it to ASP.NET MVC.  I took chunks of the app at a time, as MVC can run side-by-side with classic ASP.NET.  With making that move, IMO, MVC allows you to easily create action methods that return JSON, which plays nicely with jQuery and AJAX.  So a logical next step could be a modular move to MVC and introduce some jQuery/AJAX concepts at that time.  I'd say MVC would be the next logical step.

Comment: Not a problem - glad I could help.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Step 1) figure out what would add value for your users

Step 2) investigate technical solutions to solving those problems

Step 3) learn and build

Comment: +1 - i think this covers any suggestions i would have made.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a persistence layer and learn about entities. This is an extremely useful skill to have. You could do this by using NHibernate. I would also throw in some LINQ to get a great combo. After this i would probably go to the GUI and do some needed features with jQuery